# Pass API Filters to MongoDB Query

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have an node-express endpoint that accepts several url parameters as filters. For example

```
{{baseUrl}}/projects?page=1&name=myProject
```

The request is then translated to a mongoDB query.

Model:

```
const projectSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  users: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
});

const Project = mongoose.model('Project', projectSchema);
```

```
const filter = pick(req.query, ['name']);
const options = pick(req.query, ['sortBy', 'limit', 'page']);
options.populate = 'users';
const result = await projectService.queryProjects(filter, options, req.user);
```

This works fine, but when i use mongoDB filter expressions like "/MyProject/" the filter is passed as a string and not as an expression.

What do i need to change to get the expected result?

```
#current result
console.log(filter);
#Output: { name: '/MyProject/' }

#expected result
const test = { name: /MyProject/ };
console.log(test);
#Output { name: /MyProject/ }
```

Comment: Would you double check your expected result in this example? You might be missing something

Comment: Just checked it again. I've changed the mongoDB query to use my `test` variable instead of `filter` and i am getting the expected search result from the database. The difference in my exmaple is the ' in output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/MyProject/` (without quotes is a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)):

```
> typeof "/MyProject/"
'string'
> typeof /MyProject/
'object'
>  /MyProject/  instanceof String
false
>  /MyProject/  instanceof RegExp
true
```

Now if you want to construct a RegEx from a string you may want to consider using RegEx constructor:

```
new RegExp("MyProject")
/MyProject/
```

Or, you can read your filter as a string from your query parameters then use the other way of passing filters to MongoDB with [`$regex`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#mongodb-query-op.-regex):

```
const filter = pick(req.query, ['name']); 
const result = await projectService.queryProjects({"name": {"$regex": filter, "$options": "i"}, options, req.user);
```

---

### WARNING

Either way **please be careful when using such approaches** as they may lead to [ReDOS](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Regular_expression_Denial_of_Service_-_ReDoS) and/or NoSQL injection.